# Tengo un error indefinido al subir un archivo

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Tengo este fragmento de código que edita un producto y le agrega una imagen oculta en una carpeta y crea una url en la base de datos.

al editar el archivo y tratar de subirme tira el siguiente error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ya e buscado la manera de arreglarlo y no logro hacer que funcione, si alguien con mas experiencia me podria dar una mano ya que hace dias que vengo con el mismo error

```
<?php

    ModificarProducto($_POST['id'], $_POST['categoria'], $_POST['descripcion'] );

    function ModificarProducto($id, $nom, $descrip)
    {
        include 'conexion.php';
        echo $sentencia="UPDATE Productos SET categoria='".$nom."', descripcion='".$descrip."' WHERE id='".$id."' ";
        $con->query($sentencia) or die ("Error al actualizar datos".mysqli_error($con));
    }

    if ($_FILES["file1"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    } else 
    {

        $nom_archivo=$_FILES['file1']['name']; // Para conocer el nombre del archivo
        $ruta = "images/" . $nom_archivo;  // La ruta del archivo contiene el nuevo nombre y el tipo de extension
        $archivo = $_FILES['file1']['tmp_name']; //el arhivo a subir
        $subir=move_uploaded_file($archivo, $ruta); //se sube el archivo
        echo $sentencia_img="UPDATE Productos SET url_image='$ruta' WHERE id='".$_POST['id']."' ";
        $con->query($sentencia) or die ("Error al actualizar datos".mysqli_error($con));
        
    }

    
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("Datos Actualizados Exitosamante!!");
    window.location.href='index.php';
</script>
```

Comment: No estas incluyendo el archivo `conexion.php` fuera de la función, por lo que al entrar al `else` la variable `$con` no existe.

Comment: Te amee, muchisimas gracias, hacia tiempo venia buscando el error

Comment: Por salud mental, si uno usa con frecuencia recursos (como la conexión), se incluyen al comienzo del script. Con eso cualquier lío de include/require se ve más fácil

Comment: @MasterDesing  Si la respuesta de Marcos es correcta deberías marcarla como aceptada para que la comunidad lo sepa y no sigamos visitando esta pregunta como si estuviera pendiente, y para que otros con problemas parecidos encuentren la respuesta que te ayudó a solucionarlo. Para aprender a aceptar la respuesta visita este [enlace](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/428/263200), gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No estas incluyendo el archivo `conexion.php` fuera de la función, por lo que al entrar al `else` la variable `$con` no existe.

#### Solución:

Incluir el archivo `conexion.php` otra vez, pero fuera de la función.

**Ejemplo:**

```
<?php

ModificarProducto($_POST['id'], $_POST['categoria'], $_POST['descripcion']);

function ModificarProducto($id, $nom, $descrip)
{
    include 'conexion.php';
    echo $sentencia = "UPDATE Productos SET categoria='" . $nom . "', descripcion='" . $descrip . "' WHERE id='" . $id . "' ";
    $con->query($sentencia) or die("Error al actualizar datos" . mysqli_error($con));
}

include 'conexion.php'; // <-- ACA

if ($_FILES["file1"]["error"] > 0) {
} else {

    $nom_archivo = $_FILES['file1']['name']; // Para conocer el nombre del archivo
    $ruta = "images/" . $nom_archivo;  // La ruta del archivo contiene el nuevo nombre y el tipo de extension
    $archivo = $_FILES['file1']['tmp_name']; //el arhivo a subir
    $subir = move_uploaded_file($archivo, $ruta); //se sube el archivo
    echo $sentencia_img = "UPDATE Productos SET url_image='$ruta' WHERE id='" . $_POST['id'] . "' ";
    $con->query($sentencia) or die("Error al actualizar datos" . mysqli_error($con));
}
```